# Jolt: how to use one key for two different attributes

Tags: json, jolt

This question is similar to [With Jolt json transformation, is it possible to copy a value into two different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618761/with-jolt-json-transformation-is-it-possible-to-copy-a-value-into-two-different). But here, I want to use the whole value as one attribute and use part of the value as another attribute.

I have an input like

```
{
    "data": {
        "data1": "apple",
        "data2": "orange"
    }
}
```

I want an output like:

```
{
    "original data": {
        "data1": "apple",
        "data2": "orange"
    }
    "DATA 1": "apple"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an array from that one value. Like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "data1": ["original data.data1",
                  "DATA1"],
        "data2": "original data.data2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```